Что в Си находится в переменной до присваивания значения человеком?
Вот у меня есть код
#include <stdio.h>

void what_in_variable1(void);
void what_in_variable2(void);
void what_in_variable3(void);

int main(void)
{
    what_in_variable1();
    what_in_variable2();
    what_in_variable3();
    return 0;
}

void what_in_variable1(void)
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;

    printf("a znachenie %d\n", a);
    printf("b znachenie %d\n", b);
    printf("c znachenie %d\n", c);
}

void what_in_variable2(void)
{
    int d;
    int e;
    int f;

    printf("d znachenie %d\n", d);
    printf("e znachenie %d\n", e);
    printf("f znachenie %d\n", f);
}

void what_in_variable3(void)
{
    int q;
    int o;
    int p;

    printf("q znachenie %d\n", q);
    printf("o znachenie %d\n", o);
    printf("p znachenie %d\n", p);
}

Код возвращает сообщения
a znachenie 0
b znachenie -134327328
c znachenie 32767
d znachenie 0
e znachenie -134327328
f znachenie 32767
q znachenie 0
o znachenie -134327328
p znachenie 32767

Очевидно это не те данные которые были в памяти до того как её выделили под переменную, иначе все цифры были бы разными. По той же причине это не могут быть адреса ячеек памяти которые выделяются под переменные. При этом последняя объявленная в функции переменная всегда равна 32767, объявленная перед ней всегда равна -134327328, а ещё одна перед ней всегда равна 0. То есть если бы объявил только a и b то уже a была бы -134327328 а b была бы 32767.
Или код компилируется так что переменным до присваивания значений человеком всегда присваиваются какие-то дефолтные значения в зависимости от того в каком порядке объявлена переменная?
И если это так то можно ли как-то сделать такой код который не будет присваивать дефолтные значения переменным до присваивания значений человеком а сможет посмотреть что там было изначально? Может быть с этой ячейкой памяти раньше работала другая программа и она оставила там какие-нибудь интересные данные - куки, пароли и т.д.

Оно происходит не так. В С программист отвечает за то, что в программе отсутствует чтение неинициализированной переменой.

Там мусор. Переменные a, d, q используют одну и ту же ячейку памяти (или один и тот же регистр). Поэтому там один и тот же мусор.

в стандарте указано, что поведение программы может быть не определено. И компилятор в праве напечатать любое, удобное ему значение.

получается для всех локальных переменных которым не присвоено значение выделяются одни и те же ячейки памяти? если вставить в первую функцию c = 3; то код выведет
a znachenie -134327328
b znachenie 32767
c znachenie 3
d znachenie 3
e znachenie -134327328
f znachenie 32767
q znachenie 3
o znachenie -134327328
p znachenie 32767
В первой функции значение присвоилось последней переменной как и должно, а во всех остальных - первой. Почему порядок поменялся?

@duad, вы поменяли первую процедуру. Компилятор скомпилировал её по другому. Поменял порядок переменных на стеке. Имеет право.

Вы не поняли. Чтение из неинициализированной переменной делает программу некорректной. Термин "Неопределенное Поведение" означает, что, например, вы теряете возможность утверждать, что в строке printf("a znachenie %d\n", a); печатается значение переменной a.

@user7860670, всё так пока вы не выходите за рамки стандартного C. Но конкретный компилятор может дать дополнительные гарантии. Если вы контролируете компиляцию и её результат, вы можете рассуждать о том что делает эта программа.

@StanislavVolodarskiy Если компилятор сделать бинарь, то можно поррасуждать о том, что делает получившийся бинарь, но не о том, что делает написанная программа.

@user7860670, это казуистика. Компиляторы C делают намного больше чем написано в стандарте. Кроме того термин "неопределённое поведение" означает "неопределённое стандартом поведение". Он введён специально чтобы дать разработчикам компилятора возможность доопределить такое поведение до удобного/быстрого на данной платформе. Бинарь анализировать не обязательно, нужное поведение может быть описано в документации на компилятор/платформу.

@StanislavVolodarskiy хорошо если оно и правда написано, только ссылку-то на написанное вы и не привели...

@PavelMayorov, ваша правда, вряд ли я отыщу документацию по неинциализированным переменным. В других случаях есть дока в флагам определяющим поведение, в этом нет. Но чем плох контроль по сгенерированому коду? Нет документации, анализируем код. И в конце-концов GCC - открытый код, он сам может служить документацией. Да тяжело читать, но в результате вы будете знать что делает ваша программа.

@duad, один полезный совет -- в подобных экспериментах печатайте вместе с значением переменной и ее адрес (формат %p для printf)

@avp попробовал, выяснилось что первая переменная a всегда имеет адрес 0x7fffffffd7d8 (в VS Code адрес один и тот же, если в консоли запускать gcc то адрес при каждой компиляции другой) а все остальные (nil). как так? у них же должен быть хоть какой-то адрес в оперативке, откуда-то же эти числа берутся. на лету они генерироваться не могут, иначе бы они были каждый раз случайными.

@avp опытным путём я выяснил следующее - если нажимать f5 в VS Code то каждый раз и адрес первой переменной и значения переменных всегда будут одинаковыми у 1-4-7, у 2-5-8, у 3-6-9.
а вот в консоли gcc каждый раз выдаёт разные значения адреса первой переменной, 1-4-7 переменная всегда ноль, 2-5-8 переменная всегда большое число (иногда отрицательное), 3-6-9 переменная всегда число слегка больше 32000.
очень странно конечно.

@duad, вы во все printf-ы адрес переменной (кроме %p в строке форматов) добавить не забыли? (всюду в печати д.б. что-то вроде printf("a znachenie %d  addr %p\n", a, &a);  printf("b znachenie %d  addr %p\n", b, &b); ....). Что касается разных адресов в разных запусках, то это из-за ASLR

@avp извиняюсь, я до этого ещё не дошёл. в общем произошло волшебство - стоило мне это добавить в printf как все значения переменных стали нулями а адреса стали корректно отображаться. до этого, насколько я понял, код почему-то брал число 0x7fffffffd7d8 из регистра rdx и откусывал из него по 4 байта потому что тип int в результате получалось например число 7fff или 32767 из комментария выше.  но это гцц, а clang тоже откусывал 4 байта но сначала отнимал 1 и из 0x7fffffffd7d8 получалось 7ffe то есть 32766.

@duad, вообще-то, наверное нет никакого глубокого смысла в длительном баловстве с этим вопросом. Понятно, что не инициализированая явно переменная в стеке (или полученная из динамической памяти) содержит неизвестно что (мусор), а статическая содержит 0. Лучше еще раз прочтите замечательный ответ, который все это хорошо рассматривает, да и отметьте его заслуженной галкой

Коротко
Стандартный C: ничего нельзя сказать, неопределённое поведение.
Компилятор GCC: в переменные попадает мусор со стека, во всех трёх функциях один и тот же.
Другой компилятор может сказать что-то другое.
Операционная система иногда заботится о том чтобы одна программа не получала данные другой. Если вы работаете с чувствительными данными, их надо затирать после использования.
Длинно
Вы нарушаете правила языка C: нельзя читать переменную до присвоения ей какого-нибудь значения. Это неопределённое поведение, то есть программа может делать что угодно. Больше язык C ничего не обещает.
Но конкретный компилятор с конкретными настройками может делать что-то конкретное. Посмотрим что сделает GCC с вашим кодом:

$ gcc -S temp.c

$ cat temp.s


В temp.s лежит ассемблер программы.
main вызывает функции подряд:
main:
.LFB0:
        .cfi_startproc
        pushq   %rbp
        .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
        .cfi_offset 6, -16
        movq    %rsp, %rbp
        .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
        call    what_in_variable1
        call    what_in_variable2
        call    what_in_variable3
        movl    $0, %eax
        popq    %rbp
        .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
        ret
        .cfi_endproc

Сравним две функции. У них почти одинаковый код, кроме ссылок на строки для печати. Нас интересуют инструкции
movl    -12(%rbp), %eax,
movl    -8(%rbp), %eax,
movl    -4(%rbp), %eax.
Они копируют переменные со стека в регистр eax. rbp - указывает на вершину стека, смещения -12, -8, -4 ссылаются на разные места в стеке. Расстояние между смещениями ровно четыре байта, это размер целой переменной.
Обе функции читают байты из одного и того же места на стеке. Поэтому они читают одни и теже случайные значения:



what_in_variable1
what_in_variable2




what_in_variable1:.LFB1:        .cfi_startproc        pushq   %rbp        .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16        .cfi_offset 6, -16        movq    %rsp, %rbp        .cfi_def_cfa_register 6        subq    $16, %rsp        movl    -12(%rbp), %eax        movl    %eax, %esi        movl    $.LC0, %edi        movl    $0, %eax        call    printf        movl    -8(%rbp), %eax        movl    %eax, %esi        movl    $.LC1, %edi        movl    $0, %eax        call    printf        movl    -4(%rbp), %eax        movl    %eax, %esi        movl    $.LC2, %edi        movl    $0, %eax        call    printf        nop        leave        .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8        ret        .cfi_endproc
what_in_variable2:.LFB2:        .cfi_startproc        pushq   %rbp        .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16        .cfi_offset 6, -16        movq    %rsp, %rbp        .cfi_def_cfa_register 6        subq    $16, %rsp        movl    -12(%rbp), %eax        movl    %eax, %esi        movl    $.LC3, %edi        movl    $0, %eax        call    printf        movl    -8(%rbp), %eax        movl    %eax, %esi        movl    $.LC4, %edi        movl    $0, %eax        call    printf        movl    -4(%rbp), %eax        movl    %eax, %esi        movl    $.LC5, %edi        movl    $0, %eax        call    printf        nop        leave        .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8        ret        .cfi_endproc




Минусующий, что я сделал не так?

"Компилятор: в переменные попадает мусор со стека, во всех трёх функциях один и тот же." - это прямо вводит в заблуждение. Ну а рассматривать получившийся бинарь мало толку, так как его поведение, вообще говоря, никак не связано с исходной программой.

@user7860670, нет не вводит. Я взял конкретный компилятор, конкретные настройки, конкретную платформу и получил конкретный результат, которым можно пользоваться, например, чтобы зарабатывать деньги. Мои глаза мне говорят, что код и ассемблер очень хорошо связаны. Можете продемонстрировать "никак не связано"?

@StanislavVolodarskiy в конкретной версии компилятора в некоторых условиях исходный код и результат компиляции выглядят связанными. Однако, вы даже не попытались определить эти самые условия, при которых эта связь сохраняется.

@PavelMayorov, пока условия не определены, после каждой компиляции надо вычитывать ассемблер. Это трудно. Но это не повод говорить что за пределами стандарта жизни нет.

@StanislavVolodarskiy зачем вам вообще Си в таком случае?

@PavelMayorov, на C я напишу программу значительно быстрее чем на ассемблере. Если она стандартная, скомпилирую её. Если нет, выделю части с UB в отдельные единицы трансляции, скомпилирую их, проверю ассемблер, скомпоную программу. Везде где можно я использовал всю мощь стандарта, где нельзя, ручной контроль. Быстро, эффективно и программа делает то, что мне нужно.

@StanislavVolodarskiy ага, только теперь нужно перепроверять результат при каждом обновлении компилятора...

@PavelMayorov, да. Или оставить этот модуль на ассемблере. Все компиляторы дают гарантии на ABI, что за пределами стандарта, но на этом держатся все ОС. Или модуль на ассемблере сохраняется в качестве образца. Компиляция каждый раз делается с C, результат сравнивается с образцом. Разница приводит к ошибке сборки, программист чертыхаясь проверяет новый ассемблер и обновляет образец.

@PavelMayorov, вернёмся к исходному вопросу. ТС спросил почему так, я объяснил, так как считаю что прекрываться UB как щитом не всегда правильно. Люди эксплуатируют UB и полезно иметь представление как они это делают и что при этом происходит.

@StanislavVolodarskiy спасибо за подробный ответ. опытным путём я выяснил следующее - если нажимать f5 в VS Code то каждый раз и адрес первой переменной (если в printf засунуть %p) и значения переменных всегда будут одинаковыми у 1-4-7, у 2-5-8, у 3-6-9. а вот в консоли gcc каждый раз выдаёт разные значения адреса первой переменной, 1-4-7 переменная всегда ноль, 2-5-8 переменная всегда большое число (иногда отрицательное, это потому что оно больше чем вмещается в int?), 3-6-9 переменная всегда число слегка больше 32000. все переменные кроме первой имеют адрес (nil) вы не знаете почему?

@duad, берите отладчик (gdb подойдёт, подойдёт и любой другой) и походите по ассемблеру вашей программы по шагам. Вам будет больше пользы сделать это самому, чем полагаться на мои ответы.

@StanislavVolodarskiy я попробовал в VScode, получилось так что в самом начале в регистре rdx процессора записано 0x7fffffffd7d8 и потом значение сбрасывается в 0x0. в результате адрес первой переменной отображается как 0x7fffffffd7d8 а адрес остальных как (nil). при этом первые 4 байта (переменная же типа int) от этого значения это 7fff а это как раз 32767 из 3-6-9 переменных без значения. вопрос можно ли из первых 8 байт (то есть 7fffffff или 2147483647 в десятичной) получить -134327328 ведь 2147483647это же больше чем помещается в int поэтому число отрицательное?

@duad С особым упорством в свои рассуждениях вы используете какие-то странные предпосылки. 1) это не те данные которые были в памяти до того как её выделили под переменную, иначе все цифры были бы разными. Для начала см. Числа, цифры, хексы, буквы и другая каша в голове. Если функция what_in_variable2 переиспользует память функции what_in_variable1, то и значения неинициализированных переменных запросто могут повториться. С чего вдруг при переиспользовании одного и того же куска памяти числа станут разными?


По той же причине это не могут быть адреса ячеек памяти которые выделяются под переменные. По какой такой «той же» причине? Данное утверждение следует расписать более подробно (и с учётом написанного в предыдущем пункте). 3) у них же должен быть хоть какой-то адрес в оперативке, откуда-то же эти числа берутся. Не должен. Компилятор может в целях оптимизации не выделять для переменной место в оперативной памяти и хранить её только в регистрах процессора. А в вашем случае можно даже не читать «мусор» из регистра, а печатать какой-нибудь фиксированный литерал. Не запрещено.


Кстати, см. Как хранятся в памяти литералы? 4) во все printf-ы адрес переменной ... добавить ... произошло волшебство ... адреса стали корректно отображаться. Теперь вы в явном виде используете адреса переменных, что препятствует оптимизациям компилятора и он вынужден разместить переменные в оперативной памяти. 5) на лету они генерироваться не могут, иначе бы они были каждый раз случайными. Ага, число Пи (хотя бы с парой десятичных знаков после запятой) «на лету» тоже не сгенерировать, ибо будем получать то 3, то 2,71, а иногда даже 5.

Ваше утверждение про генерацию на лету требует развёрнутого пояснения. Что вы имеете в виду и почему? 6) при этом первые 4 байта (переменная же типа int) от этого значения это 7fff. Вы увидели в ассемблерном коде, что от значения 0x7fffffffd7d8 берутся старшие четыре байта, или просто увидели похожие числовые значения и на этом строите свои выводы? 7) ведь 2147483647 это же больше чем помещается в int. Значение 2147483647 представимо 32-битным типом int. 8) можно ли из 2147483647 получить -134327328. Можно. Умножьте 2147483647 на 0 и прибавьте -134327328.
